# How to delete a log based metrics on Cloud Logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On GCP, when I select a log based metrics I created, click the the "..." at the right and select "Delete metric", I get "No metrics deleted.".

I already cleared my web browser cache. Not sure how to fix this issue.

[image: Deletion]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Can you share screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Try through [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/metrics/delete) command.

Or through [API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.metrics/delete?apix_params=%7B%22metricName%22%3A%22projects%2Fonix4dan%2Fmetrics%2Fdan%22%7D) and make sure format is as follows projects/[PROJECT_ID]/metrics/[METRIC_ID]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have configured [roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#metrics-permissions) before deleting a custom log based metrics.